# Is there a way to see if there are updates available from a central Mercurial repostiory before pulling them?

Tags: python, mercurial, fabric

I am using Fabric to deploy my Python application from my local machine. I would like to hit our central Mercurial repository (hosted on BitBucket.org) to see if my local repository is at the same rev as the tip.

Is there a command I can call to see if there are updates available from the repository without actually pulling them?   If there are updates, I would like to halt the process so I can manually review things before I either pull down those changes or continue with the deployment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ hg help incoming
hg incoming [-p] [-n] [-M] [-f] [-r REV]... [--bundle FILENAME] [SOURCE]

aliases: in

show new changesets found in source
```

Comment: damn you're good. I had typed "hg" and it only showed the basic commands. A little "hg help" woulda gone a long way.

Answer (score 3):

Also, for completeness, you can use a GUI tool, like TortoiseHg, which has the same functionality, but presents the incoming changesets visually, like this:

[image: TortoiseHg]

Comment: I am using Fabric do do all this programatically when deploying my application

Comment: Screen capture to gif? What tool do you use for this?

Comment: I used [TechSmith Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia/). It is not a free product, but if you want/need to make screencasts, in any format, it's beyond worth the money for it.